# Max() value from subquery with SUM() & multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I try to write a mysql query that display max value of a sub query but I don't. I have this primary query that works fine. This query select total points scored by each team for a specific game :

```
SELECT team_id, SUM(points) as totalpointsscored, game_id 
FROM BOXSCORES 
WHERE season="1920" and categorie=2 
GROUP BY team_id, game_id
```

Output is like this :

```
team_id | value (points scored) | game_id
    ASM |                    98 | 9117338
    ASM |                   104 | 9117335
    ASM |                    75 | 9117324
    LEM |                   128 | 9117380
    LEM |                    97 | 9117316
    STR |                    95 | 9117334
    STR |                   102 | 9117177
    STR |                    88 | 9117469
```

I'd like to select now the max value for each team to know in what game a team scored the most. So, the output would be :

```
ASM | 104 | 9117335
LEM | 128 | 9117380
STR | 102 | 9117177
```

I try with group by and having but it doesn't work. team_id & value is ok but the game_id is always the first row & not the game_id attach to the value. Could you help me to find the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        team_id, 
        sum(points) as total_points_scored, 
        game_id,
        rank() over(partition by team_id order by sum(points) desc) rn
    from boxscores
    where season = '1920' and categorie = 2 
    group by team_id, game_id
) t
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, one solution is:

```
select 
    team_id, 
    sum(points) as total_points_scored, 
    game_id
from boxscores b
where season = '1920' and categorie = 2 
group by team_id, game_id
having sum(points) = (
    select sum(points) 
    from boxscore b1
    where b1.season = b.season and b1.categorie = b.categorie and b1.team_id = b.team_id
    group by game_id
    order by sum(points) desc
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much GMB but my Web server is installed with MySQL 5.6 and this version doesn't support windows function, isn't it ?... Another solution... ?

Comment: @Hugo49: yes. The second solution is intended for MySQL < 8.0. I just fixed it.

Comment: Many thx GMB but I got an error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by team_id, game_id' at line 15.

Comment: So sorry, new error lol : #1054 - Unknown column 'b.season' in 'where clause'

I try to add alias "b" just after my boxscores table but it's the same

Comment: When I try to delete the alias, I have no error but no result as well

Comment: I try to do the same thing like you but I got this error : `#1054 - Unknown column 'mydatabase.b.season' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I just add season & categorie in first query like this :

```
select 
    team_id, 
    sum(points) as total_points_scored, 
    game_id, season, categorie
from BOXSCORES b
where season= '1920' and categorie = 2 
group by team_id, game_id
having sum(points) = (
    select sum(points) 
    from BOXSCORES b1
    where b1.season= b.season and b1.categorie = b.categorie and b1.team_id= b.team_id
    group by game_id
    order by sum(points) desc
    limit 1
)
```